# Sympy python OR statements in solve() function

Tags: python, sympy

Suppose I had a system of equations as follows but I have the requirement that within my system of equations I need 1 of 2 statements to be true.

Example:

sympy.solve([eq1 or eq2, eq3 or eq4, eq5 or eq6,...], [vars])

When I put the or statements, it doesn't work as I intended it to work (the first eq is always evaluated). How can I express the system of equations with or as I intend?

Thanks.

Comment: Put your code please. Are you using the or operator by Python or the Or object by SymPy?

Comment: or operator not object

Answer (score 0):

Try to transform the results in sets, then use unions for *or*, intersections for *and*:

```
res1 = set(solve(eq1, x))
```

Unfortunately, this may not work is some cases (it expects the result to be a list of solutions, if complicated conditions appear, may not work).

```
In [2]: res1 = set(solve(x**2-1, x))

In [3]: res2 = set(solve(x-3, x))

In [4]: res2
Out[4]: set([3])

In [5]: res1 | res2
Out[5]: set([-1, 1, 3])

In [6]: res1 & res2
Out[6]: set([])
```

That is, the *|* operator gets the union of sets (solutions that satisfy any of the equations), while the *&* operator gets the intersection of sets (i.e. solutions that satisfy all equations).

Next version of SymPy will have the *solveset( )* function, that will always return a set or set-like object. Intersection and union will always be guaranteed to work. But until then, try something like my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the equations together. The product of two expressions is zero if one or the other is zero.

In SymPy, `solve(expr, x)` assumes that `expr = 0` (for instance, `solve(x**2 - 1, x)` gives `[-1, 1]`).

If you want to solve, for instance, `x**2 - 1 = 0` OR `x**2 - 4 = 0`, you should use `solve((x**2 - 1)*(x**2 - 4), x)`.